# Identify modified row for NSTableView bound with NSArrayController

Tags: data-binding, nstableview, key-value-observing, nsarraycontroller

I have an NSTableView bound to an NSArrayController, and have registered an observer for whenever data changes to the data fields that the array controller manages.  For example, here's a few of the addObserver calls:

```
    [_arrayController addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects.userName"     options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
    [_arrayController addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects.enabled"      options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
    [_arrayController addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects.lockSettings" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
```

After that, whenever data is changed by editing the table, my observer gets called just fine.

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath compare:@"arrangedObjects.userName"] == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        // Great, we know a userName changed somewhere in the table, but which one?
    }
}
```

The problem is, I need to know which one of the arranged objects triggered this.  If I knew the tableview row that would work as well.  It's nice to know that some userName changed somewhere, but I really need to know which one of the potentially hundreds caused the observer to be called.

Sorry for the old Objective C format of this, but some of us still have tons of legacy code to deal with.

Comment: How are the array controller and table view configured? Why do you want to observe the data changes outside the data model?

Comment: I'm implementing a multi-edit function, and frankly I'm not sure how to do it using the normal binding functionality.  Basically the idea is they can multi-select rows in the table, and editing one row duplicates the edit to all selected rows.  In that case I need to know the actual source row that was modified to duplicate to the others.  There's probably a better way but it eludes me at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**View-based table view**

Connect the text fields in the cells to an action method of the delegate of the table view. Get the row with `NSTableView` method `rowForView:` and the column with `columnForView:`.

```
- (IBAction)editAction:(id)sender {
    NSInteger row = [self.tableView rowForView:sender];
    NSInteger column = [self.tableView columnForView:sender];
    NSLog(@"Edited row: %ld, column: %ld", (long)row, (long)column);
    …
}
```

**Cell-based table view**

Implement `NSControlTextEditingDelegate` method `controlTextDidEndEditing:` on the delegate of the table view. The edited row and column are `editedRow` and `editedColumn` of the table view.

```
- (void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSInteger row = self.tableView.editedRow;
    NSInteger column = self.tableView.editedColumn;
    NSLog(@"Edited row: %ld, column: %ld", (long)row, (long)column);
    …
}
```

**Key**

There are several ways to get the key:

- Set the identifier of the column (and text field in case of a view based table view) in IB to the key.
- Get the key from the value binding:

```
NSString *key = [[tableColumnOrTextField infoForBinding:NSValueBinding] objectForKey:NSObservedKeyPathKey]; // something like "arrangedObjects.name"
NSRange aRange = [key rangeOfString:@"."];
if (aRange.location != NSNotFound)
    key = [key substringFromIndex:aRange.location + 1];
```

- Get the key from the sort descriptor of the column
- Add outlets for the columns

**Bindings solution** (no coding required)

Edit the values in a detail view. Bind the text fields and other controls to controller key `selection` of the array controller. "Allowes Editing Multiple Values Selection" is switched on by default. Works for cell-based and view-based table views.

Comment: Thanks, this is the path I'm going down for now.  I have a view-based table, so all the normal 'row updated' delegates don't get called of course since they only work for cell view based tables.